# Laravel/SQL: Query model where relationship = X

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4, eloquent

**Context**

I have three models below: listing, rooms and room types -

```
LISTING
|-----|-------------|--------------------|
| ID  |  title      |  description       |
|-----|-------------|--------------------|
| 1   | some title  |  some description  |
| 2   | some title  |  some description  |
| 3   | some title  |  some description  |
etc


ROOMS
|-----|---------------|---------------|--------------------|
| ID  |  room_type_id |  listing_id   | room_description   |
|-----|---------------|---------------|--------------------|
| 1   | 1             |  1            |  some description  |
| 2   | 2             |  1            |  some description  |
| 3   | 1             |  1            |  some description  |
etc

ROOM_TYPES
|-----|------------|
| ID  |  name      |
|-----|------------|
| 1   | Bedroom    |
| 2   | Bathroom   |
| 3   | Kitchen    |
etc
```

**Question**

I am trying to query the listings model that has X amount of room types e.g. all listings that have >= 2 Bedrooms.

I think this sql is right, just not sure how to do this in Laravel -

```
SELECT listing.id, listing.title, count(rooms.id)
FROM listing
JOIN rooms on rooms.listing_id = listing.id
WHERE rooms.`room_type_id` = 10
GROUP BY listing.id
HAVING count(rooms.room_type_id) >= 1
```

Any ideas?

PS. I am using Laravel 4

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling with a complicated SQL query, I landed up using a model accessor to achieve my goal:

On the listing model

```
public function bedroomCount()
    {
        return $this->rooms()
            ->selectRaw('listing_id, count(*) as count')
            ->where('room_type_id', '=', '1')
            ->groupBy('listing_id');
    }
```

And the query

```
$listings = Listing::
            has('bedroomCount', '>=', $x)
            ->get();
```